# C# Generics and Reflection - Passing an object to a generic method

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a method with the following signature:

```
    private string SerialiazeObj<T>(T obj)
    {
          // Do some work
    }
```

Now, I have another method which accepts an object and calls the **SerializeObj** method, as shown below:

```
    private void callSerializeObj(object obj)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        string s = SerialiazeObj<objType>((objType)obj));
    }
```

The object passed to **callSerializeObj** can be of any type.  Unfortunately, the compiler is giving me this error in the (string s = SerializeObj...) part:

```
The type or namespace 'objType' could not be found (are you missing an assembly reference).
```

I don't know if I am calling **SerializeObj** the correct way.  What is the correct way of calling the method with an object which can be of any type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use as below -

```
private void callSerializeObj(object obj)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();

       MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("SerialiazeObj", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
       MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(objType );
       object Result = generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { obj });
    }
```